# Prevent htmx from swapping the innerHTML if the response matches the innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, response, htmx

I have a message box element which uses HTMX to update it's content frequently.
I want to prevent HTMX from swapping the innerHTML of the box if the response has nothing new.
Is that possible?
Thank you

I tried this but it is not working:

```
htmx.on('#msgBox', 'htmx:beforeSwap', function(evt) {
  let response = evt.detail.xhr.response
  let currentValue = document.getElementById("msgBox").innerHTML
  console.log(response)
  if (response === currentValue) {
    evt.detail.shouldSwap = false
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please put your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `beforeSwap` event on the message box. That way, you have access to the response from the server through the `event.detail.xhr.response`, and can control swapping through `event.detail.shouldSwap`. With Vanilla JS, it would look something like:

```
document.getElementById("message-box").addEventListener("htmx:beforeSwap", (event)=>{
    let response = event.detail.xhr.response
    let currentValue = event.detail.target.value
    if (response === currentValue) {
        event.detail.shouldSwap = false
}
})
```

Comment: I editted the question.. I have tried your suggestion but it is still swapping the content of the message box.

Comment: Then you need to inspect the response to see what it contains and see how different it is.